# Docker-Compose WordPress MySql Can't Connect

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am getting a 502 Gateway error while trying to connect to my WordPress site. 
Looking at the logs I have this error.

```
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.23.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

It seems to work when I don't change the passwords and keep them all on `WordPress`. I'm assuming that the dockerfiles just use the default passwords but after looking at them I only see them grabbing from the environment. But it doesn't seem to take from my environment I set.

```
version: '2'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: *****

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8085:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ******
volumes:
    db_data:
```

I want the ***** to be the same password.

Here's a dump of my wordpress variables:

```
HOSTNAME=55333eceeda8
PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php
PHP_ASC_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-5.6.30.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=test
PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2
PHP_MD5=68753955a8964ae49064c6424f81eb3e
PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf        file        g++         gcc         libc-dev        make        pkg-config      re2c
PHP_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-5.6.30.tar.xz/from/this/mirror
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
WORDPRESS_VERSION=4.7.2
PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie
APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
GPG_KEYS=0BD78B5F97500D450838F95DFE857D9A90D90EC1 6E4F6AB321FDC07F2C332E3AC2BF0BC433CFC8B3
PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2
PWD=/var/www/html
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PHP_SHA256=a363185c786432f75e3c7ff956b49c3369c3f6906a6b10459f8d1ddc22f70805
WORDPRESS_SHA1=7b687f1af589c337124e6247229af209ec1d52c3
APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2
PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev
PHP_VERSION=5.6.30
PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I see the database password in there. Here's the SQL ones:

```
root@50ec696f0f67:/# env                                                                                                                                                                                   
HOSTNAME=50ec696f0f67
MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.17-1debian8
MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7
GOSU_VERSION=1.7
MYSQL_USER=wordpress
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I see both passwords here. So for some reason my wordpress container is getting denied by the mysql container.

Comment: And you're using the env variables in wordpress? Have you tried dumping the variables used by wordpress to see if it's the env variables?

Comment: I thought I did sent them using the docker-compose file. But I'll instance in and dump them and post what I get.

Comment: You might be right, I'm not so familiar with wordpress, but I was just wondering if maybe they're being overwritten by something hardcoded

Comment: @mickadoo no they are there. It's acting weird. I saw a bunch of examples that were able to do this, but they weren't clearly written out so I must clearly be missing something. :/

Comment: Alright so it's the `root` user and not the `wordpress` user, but I still assume the `root` user would use the `WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD`

Comment: well I'm assuming wordpress is using some environment variables if that's where it's getting the WORDPRESS_DB_HOST. Is `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` the same as the `MYSQL_PASSWORD`? Maybe in the wordpress source code you could dump the variables used right before the db connection is attempted. Then exec into the db container and check if you can login with these details. Something is not in sync between the two - just keep digging!

Comment: did that. so it tries to log in with `root` and so `root` for some reason isn't using the `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST` password. Trying to force it in someway but don't know how.

Comment: Again I'm not expert on wordpress, but does it support use of environment variables out of the box? Maybe it's using the values you during setup for your password? Is your wp-config.php using the environment variables?

Comment: so I can see the `env` variables and they are set inside the container. but yes I need to look at my wp-config.php

Comment: Ended up was my old volume was holding my old mysql database meaning my old passwords in the users table. Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**WARNING: This was the only container I had on my server so I did not mind deleting everything. Running these commands blindly can wipe out all your docker containers, volumes, etc.**

I was able to solve my problem by deleting the docker volume.

Even when you run this command:

`$ docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm -v`

does not remove volumes.

Every time I tried to create a new docker container it used my old volume that stored my old mysql database with my old mysql users table thus my old password which I would change and was wrong.

to get rid of old docker volumes use:

`docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q )`

will remove all docker volumes. then rebuild which will create a new volume with an updated table from your `env` variables.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense now. Always easy in retrospect :-) Glad you got to the bottom of it

Comment: thank you! Your help was greatly useful and appreciated :D

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. I was going mad searching why deleting container or image doesn't solve mysql password problem. All data was in the volumes. Deleting db volume solved the problem.

Comment: @Shnigi hah yes! I was going insane as well! I believe Docker needs to be more verbose about this when deleting containers and images. Maybe a different removal method where it nukes everything but I'm sure that's bottom of the totem pole for the team haha.

Answer (score 1):

A working example with modifications to your docker-compose: https://github.com/sahil87/wordpress-mysql-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

**Changes:**

Make the WORDPRESS_DB_HOST

`WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: foldername_db_1.foldername_default:3306`

This seems to be recent change in the way either docker-compose works or just the mysql image, as even I am using only that. Couldn't find any documentation on it :( , took 2 days to figure out. Hope this saves you some time!

Comment: did not work. still getting: `Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.23.0.3' (using password: YES) in - on line 22` even tried running yours.

Comment: Strange. In my version try `docker rm $(docker ps -aq); docker-compose up; docker exec -it wordpressmysqldocker_wordpress_1 bash`. Once inside docker: `apt-get update; apt-get install netcat;`. 
What's the output of `nc -zv wordpressmysqldocker_db_1.wordpressmysqldocker_default 3306` ? Also try using 172.23.0.2 instead of mysql hostname.

Comment: it was my volumes. I had to delete all my volumes using `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)` then it worked! I was able to use the old `docker-compose.yml` as well.